# Indesign resize multiple anchor object at once in

Tags: adobe-indesign, anchor-point, scale

[image]

I have a document with 350 anchored objects. I want to increase the scale of each by 20%. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more effective way (most likely through scripting), but the fastest way I can think of without scripts is:

1) As preparation: assign a shortcut to the "Transform again" function (Object > Transform Again > Transform Again). Shortcuts are assigned under "Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts"

Then:

2) Select your first object, and scale it to 120% (Object > Transform > Scale).

3) Select the next object, and press your assigned shortcut to repeat the scaling operation. Repeat for all objects.

To my knowledge, you cannot select multiple anchored objects at the same time, so doing it one at a time is the only way. The shortcut at least lets you repeat the scaling operation, so you don't have to manually access the scaling dialogue and enter 120% every time.

Comment: I know the way you said .. thanks for your help ,
loss of manual access time :(

Answer (score 1):

If your anchor object is a simple shape as the one on the question and it is attached to an Object Style, adding a stroke and increasing the stroke width to the object style will be enough to simulate this 20% plus size.

[image]